# JSF Session Managed Bean data messed up with Concurrent Access

Tags: jsf, session-state

I am working on a JSF 2.0 application.  I created a SessionScoped managed bean which stores some key data about the logged in user.  When two different users login from two different machines, the user information stored in session bean by the first login user is overridden by the second user information.    The following is the source code.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name = "sessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionManagedBean implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private SetUsers user;


public String getUsername()
{
    if (user != null)
        return user.getUsrFirstname() + " " + user.getUsrLastname();
    return "";
}

public String getUserid()
{
    if (user != null)
        return user.getUsrLoginId();
    return "";
}

public int getUserGroup()
{
    if (user != null)
        return user.getUsrGroupId();
    return 0;
}



/**
 * @return the user
 */
public SetUsers getUser()
{
    return user;
}

/**
 * @param user
 * Set the user object
 */
public void setUser(SetUsers user)
{
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

How to maintain the user specific information so that it will not be affected multiple user login?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: @kolossus: I added the source code.  Please let me know if you need other details.

Comment: Two different machines or two different windows on the same browser ? `@SessionScoped` beans are not synchronized, so you'll have to do that. Are you storing this bean somewhere ? like inside an `@ApplicationScoped` bean and returning the same reference to multiple people ?

Comment: I tested with two different machines and got the same response.  I am not storing this bean within any other scoped beans.  But the value for the session beans are setup through another @RequestScoped beans.  Also, I provided a static utility method to get the session value at any point of time.

Comment: Resolved.  Used a wrong method to retrieve the sessionBean instance from bean factory.  I used "ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext" to retrieve the bean instance.  This retrieved the bean through spring.  This is the root cause of the issue.  Modified this portion of code to retrieve it from FacesContext.  Then it is working as expected.